# Couldn't start apache

Tags: php, apache-http-server

I've installed xampp 1.7.7 on windows 7 x64 and imported configuration files from 1.7.7.

With default php.ini which is shipped in 1.7.7, apache start, but the web pages are browsed white pages and at view source there is also any code.

I changed php.ini from original file to 1.7.4 backupped, and at this time I could not start apache even at command line.

This is php.ini of 1.7.4.

```
 [PHP]


;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Language Options ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

engine = On
short_open_tag = On
asp_tags = Off
precision = 14
y2k_compliance = On
output_buffering = 4096
zlib.output_compression = Off
implicit_flush = Off
unserialize_callback_func =
serialize_precision = 100
allow_call_time_pass_reference = Off
safe_mode = Off
safe_mode_gid = Off
safe_mode_include_dir =
safe_mode_exec_dir =
safe_mode_allowed_env_vars = PHP_
safe_mode_protected_env_vars = LD_LIBRARY_PATH
disable_functions =
disable_classes =

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Miscellaneous ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
expose_php = On

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Resource Limits ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
max_execution_time = 60
max_input_time = 60
memory_limit = 128M

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Error handling and logging ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT
display_errors = On
display_startup_errors = On
log_errors = On
log_errors_max_len = 1024
ignore_repeated_errors = Off
ignore_repeated_source = Off
report_memleaks = On
track_errors = On
html_errors = On
error_log =  "D:\xampp\php\logs\php_error_log"
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Data Handling ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
variables_order = "GPCS"
request_order = "GP"
register_globals = On
register_long_arrays = Off
register_argc_argv = On
auto_globals_jit = On
post_max_size = 800M
magic_quotes_gpc = Off
magic_quotes_runtime = Off
magic_quotes_sybase = Off
auto_prepend_file =
auto_append_file =
default_mimetype = "text/html"

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Paths and Directories ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
include_path = ".;D:\xampp\php\PEAR"
doc_root =
user_dir =
extension_dir = "D:\xampp\php\ext"
enable_dl = On

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; File Uploads ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
file_uploads = On
upload_tmp_dir = "D:\xampp\tmp"
upload_max_filesize = 800M

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Fopen wrappers ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
allow_url_fopen = Off
allow_url_include = Off
default_socket_timeout = 60

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Dynamic Extensions ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

extension=php_bz2.dll
;extension=php_curl.dll
;extension=php_dba.dll
extension=php_mbstring.dll
extension=php_exif.dll
;extension=php_fileinfo.dll
extension=php_gd2.dll
extension=php_gettext.dll
;extension=php_gmp.dll
extension=php_imap.dll
;extension=php_interbase.dll
;extension=php_ldap.dll
;extension=php_mssql.dll
;extension=php_mysql_mysqlnd.dll
extension=php_mysql.dll
;extension=php_mysqli_mysqlnd.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
;extension=php_oci8.dll
;extension=php_pdo_firebird.dll
;extension=php_pdo_mssql.dll
;extension=php_pdo_mysql_mysqlnd.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
;extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
;extension=php_pdo_sqlite_external.dll
;extension=php_pgsql.dll
;extension=php_pspell.dll
;extension=php_shmop.dll
;extension=php_snmp.dll
extension=php_soap.dll
extension=php_sockets.dll
extension=php_sqlite.dll
extension=php_sqlite3.dll
;extension=php_sybase_ct.dll
;extension=php_tidy.dll
extension=php_xmlrpc.dll

[PECL]
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Module Settings ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

[Date]
date.timezone = Europe/Berlin

[Pdo_mysql]
pdo_mysql.cache_size = 2000
pdo_mysql.default_socket = "MySQL"

[Syslog]
define_syslog_variables  = Off

[mail function]
SMTP = localhost
smtp_port = 25
mail.add_x_header = Off

[SQL]
sql.safe_mode = Off

[MySQL]
mysql.allow_local_infile = On
mysql.allow_persistent = On
mysql.cache_size = 2000
mysql.max_persistent = -1
mysql.max_links = -1
mysql.default_port = 3306
mysql.default_socket = "MySQL"
mysql.default_host =
mysql.default_user =
mysql.default_password =
mysql.connect_timeout = 3
mysql.trace_mode = Off

[MySQLi]
mysqli.max_persistent = -1
mysqli.allow_local_infile = On
mysqli.allow_persistent = On
mysqli.max_links = -1
mysqli.cache_size = 2000
mysqli.default_port = 3306
mysqli.default_socket = "MySQL"
mysqli.default_host =
mysqli.default_user =
mysqli.default_pw =
mysqli.reconnect = Off

[mysqlnd]
mysqlnd.collect_statistics = On
mysqlnd.collect_memory_statistics = Off

[bcmath]
bcmath.scale = 0

[browscap]
browscap = "D:\xampp\php\extras\browscap.ini"

[Session]
session.save_handler = files
session.save_path = "D:\xampp\tmp"
session.use_cookies = 1
session.use_only_cookies = 0
session.name = PHPSESSID
session.auto_start = 0
session.cookie_lifetime = 0
session.cookie_path = /
session.cookie_domain =
session.cookie_httponly =
session.serialize_handler = php
session.gc_probability = 1
session.gc_divisor = 100
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440
session.bug_compat_42 = On
session.bug_compat_warn = On
session.referer_check =

session.entropy_length = 0
session.entropy_file =
session.cache_limiter = nocache
session.cache_expire = 180
session.use_trans_sid = 1
session.hash_function = 0
session.hash_bits_per_character = 5
url_rewriter.tags = "a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=,fieldset="

[MSSQL]
mssql.allow_persistent = On
mssql.max_persistent = -1
mssql.max_links = -1
mssql.min_error_severity = 10
mssql.min_message_severity = 10
mssql.compatability_mode = Off
mssql.secure_connection = Off


[Tidy]
tidy.clean_output = Off

[soap]
soap.wsdl_cache_enabled=1
soap.wsdl_cache_dir="/tmp"
soap.wsdl_cache_ttl=86400
soap.wsdl_cache_limit = 5

[ldap]
; Sets the maximum number of open links or -1 for unlimited.
ldap.max_links = -1

[mime_magic]
mime_magic.magicfile = "D:\xampp\php\extras\magic.mime"
;mime_magic.debug = On

[eAccelerator]
;zend_extension = "D:\xampp\php\ext\php_eaccelerator_ts.dll"

; The amount of shared memory (in megabytes) that eAccelerator will use.
; "0" means OS default. Default value is "0".
eaccelerator.shm_size = "0"
eaccelerator.cache_dir = "D:\xampp\tmp"
eaccelerator.enable = "1"
eaccelerator.debug = 0
eaccelerator.check_mtime = "1"
eaccelerator.filter = ""
eaccelerator.shm_max = "0"
eaccelerator.shm_ttl = "0"
eaccelerator.shm_prune_period = "0"
eaccelerator.shm_only = "0"

[XDebug]
;zend_extension = "D:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
zend_extension = "D:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.1.2-5.3-vc9.dll"
;프로그램 시작과 동시에 추적 시작
xdebug.auto_trace = On
;xdebug.collect_includes = 1
;xdebug.collect_params = 0
;xdebug.collect_return = 0
;xdebug.collect_vars = "Off"

; xdebug.default_enable
;xdebug.default_enable = "On"

; xdebug.dump.*
; xdebug.dump.SERVER = REMOTE_ADDR,REQUEST_METHOD
; xdebug.dump.SERVER = REMOTE_ADDR,REQUEST_METHOD
;xdebug.dump.COOKIE = ""
;xdebug.dump.FILES = ""
;xdebug.dump.GET = ""
;xdebug.dump.POST = ""
;xdebug.dump.REQUEST = ""
;스택 + 덤프 나타내기?
xdebug.dump.SERVER = "REQUEST_URI,SCRIPT_NAME"
;xdebug.dump.SESSION = ""

;xdebug.dump_globals = 1
;xdebug.dump_once = 1
;xdebug.dump_undefined = 0
;xdebug.extended_info = 1
;xdebug.file_link_format = ""
;xdebug.idekey = "netbeans-xdebug"
xdebug.idekey = "ECLIPSE_DBGP_192.168.0.2"
xdebug.manual_url = "http://kr.php.net/manual/kr/"
;xdebug.max_nesting_level = 100
xdebug.overload_var_dump = 1
xdebug.profiler_append = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "D:\xampp\tmp"
xdebug.profiler_output_name = "xdebug_profile.%R::%u"
;xdebug.remote_autostart = 0
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host = "localhost", "127.0.0.1", "appletree.codisk.com"
xdebug.remote_log = "D:\xampp\apache\logs\xdebug_remote"
xdebug.remote_mode = "req"
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
;xdebug.show_exception_trace = 0
;xdebug.show_local_vars = 0
;xdebug.show_mem_delta = 0
;xdebug.trace_format = 0
;로그를 계속 쌓이게 하기
xdebug.trace_options = 1
xdebug.trace_output_dir = "D:\xampp\tmp"
; 파일 이름 지정
xdebug.trace_output_name = "xdebug_trace"
;xdebug.trace_output_name = "trace.%c"
;xdebug.var_display_max_children = 128
;xdebug.var_display_max_data = 512
;xdebug.var_display_max_depth = 3

; Local Variables:
; tab-width: 4
; End
```

I got the error message at windows event logs of applecation.

```
Message: The description for Event ID '1000' in Source 'Application Error'
         cannot be found.  The local computer may not have the necessary
         registry information or message DLL files to display the message,
         or you may not have permission to access them.  The following
         information is part of the event:'httpd.exe', '2.2.21.0', '4e6b3136',
         'php5ts.dll', '5.3.8.0','4e537a04', 'c0000005', '000f8a80', '1790',
         '01cccc3bbfb8ec87', 'D:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe',
         'D:\xampp\php\php5ts.dll', 'fe381c65-382e-11e1-b7e9-001986002dce'
Event ID / Instance ID1000 / 1000
Date & Time: 1/6/2012 3:23 PM
Time Written: 1/6/2012 3:23 PM
Entry Type: Error
Source: Application Error
User Name: 
Category: (100)
Machine: WIN-BHF9RKQMPUS
Data:
```

Comment: And you thought not providing the error message from starting apache would help the community - you know - test their xen in guessing your problem?

Comment: There's no error message and inly empty log file. When I press "start apache" button on xampp control panel, it started and stopped. I can't understand xen.

Comment: There any no error logged anywhere for a failed process start? Why I dont like GUI OS's - go find your OS logs - rarely will a process fail to start silently - where it complains is the question

Comment: try it 2-3 times and it might work (xampp does this from time to time)

Comment: i tried several times, but same result. And I got windows event log, but I could not post here.

Comment: uninstall and try a fresh install. do not import settings. OR try the zipped XAMPP.

Comment: Just install a fresh copy and then make your changes to the configuration files manually, it saves so much time!

Comment: I know its commented out, but why are there Korean characters in your php.ini file?

Comment: Joseph the Dreamer/